# Flawed proof that $P(\mathbb N)$ is countable

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I was working through Abott's Understanding Analysis and during his discussion of power sets, I thought of the following proof that $P(\mathbb N)$ is countable:

Let $S_n$ be the set of all subsets of $\mathbb N$, whose elements sum to $n$. So $S_1 = \{\{1\}\}, S_2 = \{\{2\}\}, S_3 = \{\{1,2\}, \{3\}\}$, and so on. In this case, this construction would provide you with countably many sets, each of which is finite, and thus the union is at most countable, was the thought process I had.

The discussion in the book completely omits ZFC and I do not have any background with set theory, but the book does state that the union of countably many countable sets is also countable. I have read and understood Cantor's theorem and how he shows that no bijection exists between $S$ and $P(S$), but I couldn't work out for myself how that breaks this argument above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where does the set of even numbers show up? (This is a very reasonable question, but has appeared on this site before.)

Comment: What you discovered is that the set of all FINITE substets of $\mathbb N$ is countable. But your proof is missing all infinite subsets.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even think about infinite subsets; the question you linked me to perfectly answers my questions with the similar construction. I'd tried a few searches before posting but i'd somehow missed that discussion.